# Discord Bot type error with Client in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

If I'm gonna be honest I have 0 clue what I'm doing so I really don't know how to fix this. I'm trying to make a basic discord bot, but I get a type error when I make my client variable. Here's my code

```
import discord
import responses

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'token'
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is not running!')

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

full type error

Client.**init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
File "C:\Users\fortn\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\ggnewoah\bot.py", line 13, in run_discord_bot
client = discord.Client()
File "C:\Users\fortn\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\ggnewoah\main.py", line 4, in 
bot.run_discord_bot()
TypeError: Client.**init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

I  tried to run it but got an error on line 13

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: It appears that you accidentally posted your private discord API token; please change it now as anyone can now use it for potentially malicious purposes.

Comment: I would suggest changing that API token, as now anyone can see it in this post's edit history.

Answer (score 1):

`intents` is a required argument for initializing `discord.Client`
So, You can add the intents based on your need. If you want the bot to read messages in the channel. You can do sth like this

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

And don't forget to turn on the switch for these permissions in discord developer portal.